# Can't restrict an image size with CSS

Tags: css, background-image

I've been trying to get this background image to work and it's kinda driving me nuts.  Can't seem to figure out the right coding.

Right now, the pdficon is simply massive and not at all in the container it should be 'contained' within. I'm just not sure how to target the background image properly.

HTML code(Custom Code box):

```
<a href="<url>" style="text-decoration:none;font-family:arial;font-color:black;">
<div id="main">
<div id="first">
</div>
<div id="second">
<p>TEXT
</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
div#first {
    background-image: url('pdfIcon.png');
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity:0.2;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Gecko 1.9.2 (Firefox 3.6) */
     -o-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Opera 9.5 */
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Safari 3.0 */
    background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4.0) and other CSS3-compliant browsers */
    -moz-border-image: url('pdfIcon.png') 0;
}
div#second{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
top: 0;
left:0;
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DragonDon/1eyyjnpp/)

Comment: Restrict the size of the div...at the moment it's 100% of the viewport. http://jsfiddle.net/1eyyjnpp/2/

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D!  I can work with this!  (I'm unable to upvote at the moment, so consider this an upvote!)

Answer (score 1):

The background size "cover" property may be what you're looking for:

```
background-size: cover
```

Comment: That was something I had tried and it would not do the job.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the div with the background is so large is because it is positioned absolutely.
It's parent (#main) needs to be relatively positioned otherwise div#first will have nothing to base it's 100% width and height on except the confines of the body.

Once #main is position:relative, #first will conform to the size of it (providing you give it a width and height).

Answer (score 0):

As **@Paulie_D** said. You can simply restrict your `div#first`

but your setting the size to the image:
`background-size: 100% 100%;`

if you want the original size of the image then use:
`background-size: auto;`

and if you simply want to have a responsive background set:
`background-size: cover;`
or
`background-size: contain;`